# Create custom 404 error for each app on my django project?

Tags: python, django, custom-error-pages

is there a way to create multiple custom errors templates for each app on my Django project, I mean, in my project I got 3 apps I will show 3 different customs 404 error per each app.

Right now I'm showing the same 404 error page for my back office app and front office.

Comment: Are you talking about self raised 404 messages (such as `get_object_or_404`) or that are caused by undefined URLs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create a custom [error view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) and assign it to `handler404` variable in your root `urls.py`:

```
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found

def my_error_404(request, exception):
    template_name = '404.html'
    if request.path.startswith('/backoffice/'):
        template_name='backoffice/404.html'
    elif request.path.startswith('/frontoffice/'):
        template_name='frontoffice/404.html'
    return page_not_found(request, exception, template_name=template_name)
```

This code is for django 1.9.  If you use django <= 1.9 then remove the `exception` parameter from the view.